# Get a number after a word pattern in R

Tags: r, regex, data.table, match, text-extraction

I need to get the number after a word in a data table column, for example:

```
y = data.table(status =c( "client rating 01 approved", "John Rating: 2 reproved", "Customer rating9") )
```

Then, I need to get the number after the word rating and create a new column with that rating number, in the example, it should be: `rating = c(1,2,9)`.

How could I do that considering the variations after the rating like :, double space, no space?

Comment: In those examples, `as.integer(gsub("\\D", "", status))` would work, but from your question I'm inferring that you have other examples without "rating" in them.

Comment: You need to be precise about your requirements. Instead of "...like :, double space, no space...", tell us *exactly* what may appear between "rating" and the digit(s). Pretend you are writing a code spec, where there's no place for "like" or vagueness generally. (In fact, writing SO questions that are precise and unambiguous is good practice for writing code specs.)

Comment: If zero or more characters other than letters and digits can appear between "rating" and the digit(s), consider the regular expression `\brating[^a-z\d]*(\d+)` (not in R format) which has a capture group that will contain the digit(s) if there is a match.  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/djoLVH/2/). If the rule for what may appear between "rating" and the digit(s) differs from what I've assumed, change the regex accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `sub` to capture the digits (`\\d+`) after the 'rating' including characters `:` or spaces, and convert to `numeric` with `as.numeric`

```
library(data.table)
y[, num := as.numeric(sub(".*rating[^0-9]*(\\d+)\\b.*", "\\1",
         status, ignore.case = TRUE))]
y
#                      status num
#1: client rating 01 approved   1
#2:   John Rating: 2 reproved   2
#3:          Customer rating9   9
```

Comment: Gustavo, akrun has provided a very good solution and one which you may wish to select, but be mindful that a quick selection can discourage other answers and may not be appreciated by those still working on their answers. The point is there is no rush, just don't forget to make a selection if you find at least one of the answers to be helpful.  Most askers who have been at SO for awhile wait at least a couple of hours; some wait much longer, giving time for then-sleeping members an opportunity to answer.

Comment: You may wish to add word breaks to avoid matching, for example, `"grating"`.

Comment: the word break might have an issue with the last case. I added `[^0-9]*`